# How to accrue values that are being calculated on a monthly basis by a For Next Loop with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, aggregate

I've been searching everywhere for a solution but I can't seem to find one.  What I am doing is calculating the amortization schedule for a loan that has a starting balance of $240 on 1/1/2018 and pays 7% interest semi-annually. My code calculates the interest each month but I can't figure out a way to calculate the accrued interest each month and then reset it every six months (since it is paying semi annually).  I've created the amortization in excel and based on period `1 = 1/1/2018` the loan would pay interest of $85.05 on 6/2018 and $47.25 on 12/2018

The error that I'm getting is when I call the `Calculate_Accrued_Interest` subroutine it says `Expected Array` for `loan_accrued_int(period - 1)`, which makes sense to me but I don't know how else to grab the previous iteration. Also, note that I declared all variables in a separate global sheet.  For instance the modperiod array looks like this in excel

```
MOD Date  
1   1/1/2018  
2   2/1/2018  
3   3/1/2018  
4   4/1/2018  
5   5/1/2018  
0   6/1/2018  
1   7/1/2018  
2   8/1/2018  
3   9/1/2018  
4   10/1/2018    
5   11/1/2018    
0   12/1/2018  
1   1/1/2019  
2   2/1/2019  
3   3/1/2019  
4   4/1/2019
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim period             As Long

Sub Calculate_Accrued()


    For period = 1 To 16
            Call Calculate_Prepayments
            Call Calculate_Monthly_Interest
            Call Calculate_Accrued_Interest

    Next period

End Sub

Sub Calculate_Prepayments()


    If loan_cur_bal > 1# Then
        loan_prepays = 15
        loan_cur_bal = loan_cur_bal - loan_prepays
    End If

End Sub

Sub Calculate_Monthly_Interest()



    If loan_cur_bal > 1# Then
        loan_monthly_int = loan_cur_bal * 0.07
    End If

End Sub

Sub Calculate_Accrued_Interest()

    loan_accrued_int = 0#
    If loan_cur_bal > 1# Then
        If period = 1 Then
            loan_accrued_int = loan_monthly_int
        Else
            If modperiod(iperiod) = 1 Then
                loan_accrued_int = loan_monthly_int
            Else
                loan_accrued_int = loan_monthly_int + loan_accrued_int(period - 1)
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like `loan_accrued_int` is `Double` , not an array. If you want you can store several `Double` inside an array called `loan_accrued_int() ` and then work on `loan_accrued_int (period)` with a `for` loop.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on that logic.  Any chance you can show an example of what the code would look like? It would be much appreciated

Comment: I'm away from my pc today but I can reference you to [this article](http://patorjk.com/programming/tutorials/vbarrays.htm) that helps understand what is an `array` and how to use it